# Loop through the sum of the two inputs until in doubled (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, input

I am stuck here with duch issue. There are 2  two entry boxes are for an amount and an interest rate (%). 
If you click on the button, the page will show an overview of the balance until the amount have to be doubled. 
Taking a simple numbers forexample 10 - is amount and 4 -  is 4% intereste rate. So the result have to stop on amount of 20.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = loop;

var inputB = document.getElementById("inputB");
var inputC = document.getElementById("inputC");
var result = document.getElementById("result")


 function loop() {
    var s = inputB.value;
    var r = inputC.value;
    var doubleS = s * 2;
    for (var i = 1; i <= doubleS; i++) {
        s = ((r / 100 + 1) * s);
        result.innerHTML += s + "<br>";
    }
 }
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<br>
<input type="text" id="inputB" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" id="inputC"  value="4"><br><br>


<button id="button">Klik</button>

<p> De ingevoerde resultaten: </p>
<p id="result"></p>

<script async src="oefin1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your `for` loop bounds.

This will loop `doubleX` number of times: `for (var i = 0; i < doubleX; i++)`

This will loop **until** `x` surpasses `doubleX`: `for (;x < doubleX;)`, which btw is better written with a `while` loop: `while (x < doubleX)`

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = loop;

var inputB = document.getElementById("inputB");
var inputC = document.getElementById("inputC");
var result = document.getElementById("result")

function loop() {
  var s = inputB.value;
  var r = inputC.value;
  var doubleS = s * 2;
  result.innerHTML = '';
  while (s < doubleS) {
    s = ((r / 100 + 1) * s);
    result.innerHTML += s + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputB" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" id="inputC" value="4"><br><br>

<button id="button">Klik</button>

<p> De ingevoerde resultaten: </p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I've added `result.innerHTML = ''`, this is sufficient. Though note, using `innerHTML` is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just use a for loop without the convoluted math with s in the middle:

```
function loop() {
    var s = inputB.value;
    var r = inputC.value;
    var doubleS = s * 2;
    for (var i = s; i <= doubleS; i *= ((r / 100) + 1)) {
        result.innerHTML += i + "<br>";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a while loop and check is the value of s is bigger than or equal to doubleS

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = loop;

var inputB = document.getElementById("inputB");
var inputC = document.getElementById("inputC");
var result = document.getElementById("result")


 function loop() {
    var s = inputB.value;
    var r = inputC.value;
    var doubleS = s * 2;
    while(true) {
        s = ((r / 100 + 1) * s);
        result.innerHTML += s + "<br>";
        if(s >= doubleS){
           break
        }
    }
 }
```

```html
 <! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<br>
<input type="text" id="inputB" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" id="inputC"  value="4"><br><br>


<button id="button">Klik</button>

<p> De ingevoerde resultaten: </p>
<p id="result"></p>

<script async src="oefin1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: at the very beggining of the loop function set `result.innerhtml` to `""`